# How to input parameters in a job

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to input specific arguments by console to get a job running, like this:

```
@Value("#{jobParameters['inputFileName']}")
public void setFileName(final String name) {
    inputFileName = name;
}
```

The input argument is inputFileName that is defined as "ficheroEntrada.csv", like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/voJbK.jpg

But I am getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFileName' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:666) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
                at com.santalucia.batch.md_mig.Application.main(Application.java:25) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
                at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1085) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
                at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217) ~[spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:91) ~[spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:52) ~[spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88) ~[spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:111) ~[spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:265) ~[spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:161) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
                ... 22 common frames omitted
```

I am new to the spring-batch world and I don´t really know what I am doing wrong...

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind a job parameter, you need to use the [late binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding) feature with the [`StepScope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/StepScope.html).

What you need to do is to make the bean in which your setter is defined as step-scoped. A typical way to do it in your case is to declare the item reader as a bean and pass the job parameter as follows:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader flatFileItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['inputFileName']}") String name) {
   return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Foo>()
               .name("flatFileItemReader")
               .resource(new FileSystemResource(name))
               // set other properties on the reader
}
```

Comment: That being said, Spring can do the type conversion for you and you can just inject a `Resource` instead of the String in this case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring you should be able to get a hold on command line arguments by using the `@Value` annotation with the `${}` syntax.

```
public void setFileName(@Value("${inputFileName}") final String name) {
    inputFileName = name;
}
```

Obviously the `@Value` annotation works on objects which are managed (and sometimes proxied) by the Spring context (Beans).

Comment: Even if I delete the "jobParameters" syntax, I am getting the same error...

Comment: @Albertus_Farray You don't have to. It should be already managed by Spring. Can you post the class code?

Comment: Yeah I can post It, let me a second